# How to get the last element of a column in a huge CSV using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

My CSV is 30 GB in size, so I can't open it. Thus, to find out the first and the last rows of a column, I had to write a code. This is my code:

```
require 'csv'

COLUMNS = ['timestamp']
i=0
CSV.foreach('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\1433825596_209257.csv', :headers=>true).map do |row|
    date_column = COLUMNS.map { |col| row[col] }
    i=i+1
end
first=date_column(2)
last=date_column(i)
```

All I'm trying to do here is store the `timestamp` column in an array, `date_column`, and then once the loop exits, print out the first (2 because it has a header) and the last element of the array. But when I run it, it never ends, and keeps running forever. So, what is wrong in my code? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why it would run _forever_. It just takes a long time. Try printing values of `i`, for example.

Comment: Also, your logic around `date_column` seems a bit weird to me, but it shouldn't cause infinite loops

Comment: I left it to run, and came back after 4 hours. It still had not halted. The CSV file took 4-5 hours to generate, and it had 42 columns. So, considering that, wouldn't you say there's something wrong if it can't finish counting the number of elements in only one column? It should have been over in, like, 1 hour I think; it has about 19-20 million rows. Also, what's weird about my logic around `date_column`? I'm very new to Ruby, so I have not studied the syntax in detail. I'm using the logic from C. Is there a better, more efficient way to find the last element of an array in Ruby?

Comment: The weird part about your logic is that `date_column` will never contain more than one item. So both `date_column[2]` and `date_column[i]` will return `nil`

Answer (score 2):

- Using `map` means you are opening the entire file at once, which is what you are trying to avoid.
- It is not clear what you are trying to do by iterating over `COLUMNS`, which is `['timestamp']`.
- The variable `i` does not look useful; if you wanted to access the last element of an array, you can use `last`.
- You cannot access an array's element by doing `date_column(2)`.
- In doing `first=date_column(2)` and `last=date_column(i)`, you probably have in mind a system of indexation starting with `1`. That is rare in programming. In most languages, index starts with `0`, and you should have `1` and `i - 1` (that latter of which shouldn't be neccessary).
- From what looks like you are trying to do, you need to initialize `date_column` outside of the iteration.

Probably your code should look along this line:

```
file = "C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\1433825596_209257.csv"
date_column = []
CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
  # Do something with `date_column` and `row`
  #   (Perhaps `push` some elements of `row` into `date_column`
  #   depending on a condition?)
end
first, last = date_column[1], date_column.last
```

Comment: Ah, it has `map` after `foreach`. Yeah, that will totally explain the "forever" part :)

Comment: If it were me who was tasked with this, I'd not bother with reading the whole file at all. Read the first line, determine position of the needed column. Seek to the near-end of the file, find the last line there. Parse and get the needed value. Should be super-fast.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It is not even clear to me whether the OP actually means "column" or "row". The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for loop counters, header offsets, column arrays or anything of that sort. You want first and last values? Iterate the collection and update current values accordingly

```
require 'csv'

first_timestamp = nil
last_timestamp = nil

CSV.foreach('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\1433825596_209257.csv', :headers=>true) do |row|
    first_timestamp ||= row['timestamp'] # don't reset it
    last_timestamp = row['timestamp']
end

# do something with the timestamps
```

Comment: Ah! I see. But isn't `foreach` supposed to be like the `for` loop in C, which would mean that `first_timestamp` and `last_timestamp` would get updated every time the loop runs? If not, how does `foreach` work? And what's the difference between `CSV.foreach` and `CSV.parse`? Many thanks.

Comment: `first_timestamp` will only be set once because of the `||=` operator.

Comment: Ok. But when I wrote your program, and added at the bottom `puts first_timestamp ` and `puts last_timestamp `, the program does not display anything. Why is that so?

Comment: Is there a column `'timestamp'`? Did you run my code exactly as-is or did you add your own stuff? Some functions, perhaps?

Comment: No, I copied your code exactly as it is. I only added the 2 `puts` lines at the end outside of the loop.

Comment: Hm, should have worked. Try changing them to instance variables (`@first_timestamp`)